# Uniquely identify files with same name and size but with different contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, filenames, filesize

We have a scenario in our project where there are files coming from the client with the same file name, sometimes with the same file size too. Currently when we upload a file, we are checking the new file name with the existing files in the database and if there is a reference we are marking it as duplicate and would not allow to upload at all. But now we have a requirement to check the content of the file when they have the same file name. So we need to find out a solution to differentiate such files based on contents. So, how do we efficiently do that - meaning how to do it avoiding even a minute chance of error?

> Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.3

Below is one option I have read from a web reference.

```
require 'digest'
digest_value = Digest::MD5.base64digest(File.read( file_path ))
```

And the above line will read all the contents of the incoming file and based on which it will generate a unique hash, right? Then we can use it for unique file identification. But we have more than 500 users simultaneously working in 24/7 mode and most of them will be doing this operation. So, if the incoming file has a huge size (> 25MB) then the Digest will take more time to read the whole contents and there by suffer performance issues. So, what could be a better solution considering all these facts?

Comment: why don't you give every uploaded file a unique, generated id, independent of it's name, type, or contents?

Comment: @maxpleaner: A Random ID? We also have to find out duplicates based on content. Now, if a file comes with the same name, we say it is duplicate. But there can be situation where the file_name, even the file_size can be the same. So, we need to uniquely identify the files based on content and then if that is also same, throw the message 'File is duplicate'.

Answer (score 3):

I have read the question and the comments and I have to say you have the problem stated not 100% correct. It seems that what you need is to identify identical content. Period. Despite whether name and size are equal or not. Correct me if I am wrong, but you likely don’t want to allow users to update 100 duplicates of the same file just because the user has 100 copies of it in local, having different names.

So far, so good. I would use the following approach. The file name is not involved anyhow. The file size might help in terms of fast-check the uniqueness (sizes differ hence files are definitely different.)

Then one might allow the upload with an instant “OK” response. Afterwards, the server in the background should run `Digest::MD5`, comparing the file against all already uploaded. If there is a duplicate, the new copy of the file should be removed, *but the name should stay on the filesystem, being a symbolic link to the original*.

That way you’ll not frustrate users, giving them an ability to have as many copies of the file as they want under different names, while preserving the HDD volume at the lowest possible level.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. With the way you have perceived my question, I think your answer seems to be much valid! But, let me explain it to you in detail. A user uploads a single file at a time and we need to validate the new file with the existing files (database). Check the content only if the file names are similar and if the file names are similar we can check for its size to differentiate it. But compared to size, the content checking will be more accurate. I don't want to upload duplicate files at all. Also, we don't need to check for content if 2 files are having different names.